# Need assistance with HTML Layout's Skeleton please

Tags: html

[image]

I know this is trivial but I can't seem to get it. Could someone show me how the very basic html skeleton of this template should be? I've been able to do it using tables but I know that's a big no-no.

Either XHTML strict or HTML5 would be ok.

Comment: What, specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: Should it work "perfectly" in IE6?

Comment: Everything really Sam :(. I'm no good at html. I'm trying to teach myself and wanted to see how it should be done from someone who knows.

Comment: And it doesn't have to danp. I know IE is a pain, and an older version has to be even worse...

Answer (score 2):

```
<body>
  <h1>LOGO</h1>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li>menu item</li> 
    <li>menu item</li>
    <li>menu item</li> 
    <li>menu item</li>
    <li>menu item</li> 
    <li>menu item</li>
  </ul>

  <div class="article">
    <h2>HEADER</h2>
    <div class="content">
      <p>CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT</p>
      <p>CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT</p>
      <p>CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="article">
    <h2>HEADER</h2>
    <div class="content">
      <p>CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT</p>
      <p>CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT</p>
      <p>CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="article">
    <h2>HEADER</h2>
    <div class="content">
      <p>CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT</p>
      <p>CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT</p>
      <p>CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <p class="copyright">COPYRIGHT</p>
    <ul id="sitemap">
      <li>menu item</li>
      <li>menu item</li>
      <li>menu item</li>
      <li>menu item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>
```

as an exercise, convert it to html5 yourself :) it should be fairly easy: http://html5tutorial.net/

Comment: Ah, muchas gracias corroded! :)

Comment: +1 Nice, it's close to how I would have suggested to do it. Two things: The logo and nav elements are probably going to need a `div` around them. And the individual articles may or may not need the `div class="article"` and `div class="content"` around them, depending on the desired outcome.

Comment: since h1 and uls are block elements i usually just leave them without the extra div :) but to each his own eh? and yes, the extra div article and content usually don't need that except when you're floating. just keeping the options open :)

Comment: Yup this is pretty much how most of my stuff gets structured except I wouldn't usually give `h2` a class.

Comment: another good point. yeah i guess that's a bit overboard. i just got carried away since the company im working on now has like 1923871 types of headers. go figure -_-